# How to display value of only one datapoint in line chart

Tags: linechart, chart.js

By default while displaying line chart in `chart.js`. The tooltip shows values for all datasets present.

How to display value of only one dataset point when we hover mouse over that dataset point instead of all dataset points

Comment: I'm having the same issue, it only shows the number. But it works when there is more than 1.

Answer (score 1):

The `nearest` tooltip option might be what you're looking for.

[Working example JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hawou5wm/)